# How to join a table with a 'valid_from' and 'valid_to' column to a table with a timestamp?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working in PySpark and have a table which contains sales data for specific articles, with one row per date and article:

```
#ARTICLES
+-----------+----------+
|timestamp  |article_id|
+-----------+----------+
| 2018-01-02|   1111111|
| 2018-01-02|   2222222|
| 2018-01-02|   3333333|
| 2018-01-03|   1111111|
| 2018-01-03|   2222222|
| 2018-01-03|   3333333|
+-----------+----------+
```

Then, I have a smaller table which contains price data for each article. Prices are valid from some date to some other date, which is specified in the last two columns:

```
#PRICES
+----------+-----+----------+----------+
|article_id|price|from_date |to_date   |
+----------+-----+----------+----------+
|   1111111| 8.99|2000-01-01|2999-12-31|
|   2222222| 4.29|2000-01-01|2006-09-05|
|   2222222| 2.29|2006-09-06|2999-12-31|
+----------+-----+----------+----------+
```

In the last two rows here, you see that this price has been reduced on 2006-09-06.

I would now like to join the price to the first table. It has to be the price on its respective timestamp. In this example, I'd like the following result:

```
#RESULT
+-----------+----------+-----+
|timestamp  |article_id|price|
+-----------+----------+-----+
| 2018-01-02|   1111111| 8.99|
| 2018-01-02|   2222222| 2.29|
| 2018-01-02|   3333333| null|
| 2018-01-03|   1111111| 8.99|
| 2018-01-03|   2222222| 2.29|
| 2018-01-03|   3333333| null|
+-----------+----------+-----+
```

How would I best do this?

One idea I had was to "roll out" the price table to contain one row per timestamp and article_id, and then join using those two keys. But I wouldn't know how to roll out the table using the two date columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to do an left join and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.where()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.where) to pick the `price`.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
articles.alias("a").join(prices.alias("p"), on="article_id", how="left")\
    .where(
        f.col("p.article_id").isNull() |  # without this, it becomes an inner join
        f.col("timestamp").between(
            f.col("from_date"),
            f.col("to_date")
        )
    )\
    .select(
        "timestamp",
        "article_id",
        "price"
    )\
    .show()
#+----------+----------+-----+
#| timestamp|article_id|price|
#+----------+----------+-----+
#|2018-01-02|   1111111| 8.99|
#|2018-01-02|   2222222| 2.29|
#|2018-01-02|   3333333| null|
#|2018-01-03|   1111111| 8.99|
#|2018-01-03|   2222222| 2.29|
#|2018-01-03|   3333333| null|
#+----------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

Join with between condition should work.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
articles.alias('articles').join(prices.alias('prices'), 
   on=(
        (col('articles.article_id') == col('prices.article_id')) & 
        (col('articles.timestamp').between(col('prices.from_date'), col('prices.to_date')))
   ),
   how='left'
).select('articles.*','prices.price')
```

Comment: I thought this should work but I am not getting the correct results. Also that double `&` is a syntax error. Changing it to a single `&` results in an empty DataFrame. Could be an issue with spark versions (I'm using 2.1).

Comment: Wrapping the `prices.from_date` and `prices.to_date` in the `between` with `col()` almost gives the correct result, but it does not include the rows where the price is `null`.

Comment: Updated! I've missed that condition. It actually should be `left` join, but not inner.

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another way of achieving your desired result

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
result = articles.alias('articles').join(prices.alias('prices'), (f.col('articles.article_id') == f.col('prices.article_id')) & (f.col('articles.timestamp') > f.col('prices.from_date')) & (f.col('articles.timestamp') < f.col('prices.to_date')), 'left')\
    .select('articles.*','prices.price')
```

`result` should be

```
+----------+----------+-----+
|timestamp |article_id|price|
+----------+----------+-----+
|2018-01-02|2222222   |2.29 |
|2018-01-03|2222222   |2.29 |
|2018-01-02|3333333   |null |
|2018-01-03|3333333   |null |
|2018-01-02|1111111   |8.99 |
|2018-01-03|1111111   |8.99 |
+----------+----------+-----+
```